# When embedding an OLEObject (Word/XLS/PDF doc) into Excel via powershell, unable to save that

Tags: excel, powershell, createoleobject

When I embedding an OLEObject (Word/XLS/PDF doc) into Excel via powershell, I'm unable to save the excel file (I'd like to save manually, not via PShell - but does not work automatically either). If I insert object like *.txt, png,jpeg - there is no problem with saving the target excel file (both auto and manually saving works).

Any idea? Thanks.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
$missing=[System.Type]::missing

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.visible=$true
$wrkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$wrksheet = $wrkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$file = ("link")

  $icon =$wrksheet.OLEObjects().Add($missing,$file,$false,$false,$missing,$missing,$missing,$missing,$missing,$missing,$missing)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [tour] and [ask] and try to offer an [mcve] of what you tried so that others can understand easier where the probleme is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Is it appropriate now? :)

Comment: Yeah thats better! It probaly would be even better if you would show how you save the file ;)

Comment: Thanks, post corrected with more details (I'd like to save manually - not via PS). I hope someone can help in it. :)